# CentOS EPEL install, bitness-independent command

Tags: centos, bash, 32bit-64bit, epel

I'm writing a small 'install script' and it requires EPEL on CentOS. The command (repo url) differs according to OS bitness, how do I unify this into one command?

References: [How to install EPEL](http://gembuls.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/how-to-install-epel-repository-on-centos/)

I remember doing this with `uname`, but am not sure how to incorporate it into the existing command.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with `uname -i` and `cat /etc/redhat-release`. This would give the following:

```
[bart@dev ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.2 (Final)
[bart@dev ~]$ uname -i
x86_64
```

I would script it like this:

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/`uname -i`/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

(didn't test, and you would need to catch some exceptions like 404s)

Comment: ``rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/`uname -i`/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm`` <- is this it? Also, since it will be running on CentOS 5 only, I don't have to handle other versions. Perhaps an add-n in the future, but not needed right now.

Comment: Updated above :-).

Answer (score 1):

uname -i should output the architecture on many systems (it does on some of my i386 systems but unknown for others). If for some reason you needed to get machine type, uname -m would work.

You'd likely want to store this as a variable 
include the line
`arc=$(uname -i)` in your script, and use the variable $arc as needed